# PHP SMTP Mail class issue

Tags: php, pear

Ok here is the issue. I send an html email to my users.

I can't just send content text/html html in my headers because my host don't like it! They suggested to use SMTP.

So I had to install Pear id did. Then I had to install the Mail extension. I did.
Now I grab a code from the web to try it out and I get the error message

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mail' not found in /home/alain/php/Mail/mail.php on line 51
```

I'm calling that file with a `require_once();`. Now the line 51 in mail.php is

`class Mail_mail extends Mail {`

Its only the class statement!! The installation is brand new. The host use Cpanel

Answer (score 6):

I found out that by default the Ubuntu's `php-pear` does **not** include the PEAR::Mail package. It's easily fixable, though:

```
pear install Mail
pear install pear/Net_SMTP 
pear install pear/Auth_SASL
```

If that does not work, you might want to check your PEAR installation, by following this guide: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php

Comment: Same issue with my Ubuntu server. Thank you!
Version: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise

Answer (score 1):

You need to require() the file that has the `Mail` class, otherwise your Mail_mail class has nothing to extend.

Comment: @ZeroG: In that case, you are requiring the wrong file or have the include path setup wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the mail.php.

firstly make sure you require('../php/Mail/mail.php) before doing any email coding.

Then open up the php/Mail/mail.php and put the following code in before the first class:

```
require('../php/Mail.php')
```

for some reason the coding in the hasnt included this and the class Mail it extends cannot be reached.